Netgate 6100 Will Not Acknowledge Lastest Versions of pfSense (When Checking For Updates)
I find it strange that this Netgate 6100, I'm currently logged into, claims to be on the latest version of pfSense, yet the build is from February of 2023:

Other Netgate models I've logged into have later versions of pfSense than this. Why is it that this Netgate 6100 doesn't acknowledge any of those 24.x releases and provide the ability to upgrade to them when checking for updates?

It turns out that this Netgate 6100 was set to a "Deprecated Version" branch.
I found this under: System > Update > System Update > Branch
"Latest Stable" wasn't an available branch option, so I changed the branch to the latest stable shown, which was "Previous Stable Version 23.09".
After upgrading to 23.09, I went back to see what branch options were now available. "Current Stable" still wasn't an option, but now I could change to "Previous Stable Version 23.09.1".
Then, after upgrading to 23.09.1, the branch "Current Stable 24.03" became available, so I changed to that branch and upgraded once more.
I think it is a bit silly that I had to change the branch over an over again to finally achieve running the latest stable, but that's what I had to do.
My feedback to pfSense is to add an option to the Branch drop-down-menu that is simply "Current Stable" (without the mention of any particular version number). If you're on a deprecated branch, you shouldn't have to change the branch 3 times in order to finally upgrade to the latest stable.
Upgrading 3 times was understandable, and the granularity to remain on a particular branch/version is also a nice flexibility. Yet, most people would probably appreciate a more generic branch option (like I'm proposing above), so that they can always upgrade to the latest stable version without having to modify branches each time between each upgrade.
